# Questions about one file copy

Tags: python, multithreading, process, file-copying

I have used python to make testing of copy large file by different ways and compare the time consumptions, but i got a unexpectation answer compared with the theory, multiple processes or threads copy consumed much more time compared with single thread copy, i didnt know why, anyone can explain ? the code as follows:

```
    import os
    import time
    import shutil
    import multiprocessing
    from threading import *
    from multiprocessing import Process

    dest = 'D:\\temp\\empty\\winx64_12201_database.zip'
    src = 'D:\\05 软件\\winx64_12201_database.zip'
    thread_size = 10
    process_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()


    def copy():
        shutil.copy(src, dest)


    def copyStream():
        source = src
        destination = dest
        if os.path.isfile(destination):
            os.remove(destination)
        copied = 0
        source = open(source, "rb")
        target = open(destination, "wb")
        while True:
            chunk = source.read(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            target.write(chunk)
            copied += len(chunk)
        source.close()
        target.close()


    def multiCopy():
        source = src
        source_size = os.stat(source).st_size
        if source_size%thread_size == 0:
            block_size = source_size / thread_size
        else:
            block_size = round(source_size / thread_size)
        threads = []
        for thread_id in range(thread_size):
            thread = CopyWorker(source_size, block_size, thread_id)
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
        for t in threads:
            if t.is_alive():
                t.join()


    class CopyWorker(Thread):
        def __init__(self, source_size, block_size, tid):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.source_size = source_size
            self.block_size = block_size
            self.tid = tid

        def run(self):
            source = open(src, "rb")
            target = open(dest, "wb")
            start_position = self.block_size * self.tid
            end_position = start_position + self.block_size
            if end_position > self.source_size:
                end_position = self.source_size
            source.seek(int(start_position))
            target.seek(int(start_position))
            while start_position < end_position:
                if (start_position + 1024) < end_position:
                    chunk = source.read(1024)
                else:
                    chunk = source.read(int(end_position - start_position))
                if not chunk:
                    break
                target.write(chunk)
                start_position += 1024
            source.close()
            target.close()


    def copyMulti():
        source = src
        source_size = os.stat(source).st_size
        if source_size % process_size == 0:
            block_size = source_size / process_size
        else:
            block_size = round(source_size / thread_size)
        processes = []
        for process_id in range(process_size):
            process = Process(target=copyWorker, args=(source_size, block_size, process_id))
            process.start()
            print(process.pid)
            processes.append(process)
        for p in processes:
            if p.is_alive():
                p.join()


    def copyWorker(source_size, block_size, pid):
        source = open(src, "rb")
        target = open(dest, "wb")
        start_position = block_size * pid
        end_position = start_position + block_size
        if end_position > source_size:
            end_position = source_size
        source.seek(int(start_position))
        target.seek(int(start_position))
        while start_position < end_position:
            if (start_position + 1024) < end_position:
                chunk = source.read(1024)
            else:
                chunk = source.read(int(end_position - start_position))
            if not chunk:
                break
            target.write(chunk)
            start_position += 1024
        source.close()
        target.close()



    if __name__ == '__main__':

        print("========== Single thread Copy ==========")
        time_0 = time.time()
        copy()
        print("End：", time.time() - time_0, "\n")

        print("========== Single thread stream Copy ==========")
        time_0 = time.time()
        copyStream()
        print("End：", time.time() - time_0, "\n")

        print("========== Multi threads stream Copy ==========")
        time_0 = time.time()
        multiCopy()
        print("End：", time.time() - time_0, "\n")

        print("========== Multi processes stream Copy ==========")
        time_0 = time.time()
        copyMulti()
        print("End：", time.time() - time_0, "\n")
```

Comment: How big are your test files? A 1kb chuck is very tiny. Depending on your filesystem, your HD might be using 512 byte blocks, or on more modern systems 2kb blocks. In either case, you're wasting a lot of time slicing the file up into such tiny chunks. Try a larger chunk size, eg 64kb. IME, that gives good results (but I have a very old 32 bit machine), and you may notice some improvements with chunk sizes up to a megabyte, or even larger, depending on your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i have tested 10kb, 100kb, 1mb, the results are the same.